# Enumerate all possible event log entries in HippoCMS

Tags: logging, hippocms

I'm trying to identify what user activities are recorded to the audit log in a Hippo CMS instance. My goal is to asses whether the entries are sufficiently detailed to conform to a customer's audit requirements.

For what I understand, these events are generated from the "workflow" and since this is extendable, the answer depends on the collection of plugins contained in the project.

Therefore the question can be phrased as: how can I find out which events are present? Is there an event registry one can query to enumerate all potentially emittable events? Alternatively, what should I grep for in the source code to collect this information?

Best,
Edoardo